# How do I compile Java code on Centos 5?

Tags: java, linux

In windows I can use this command:

```
java -cp server.jar;mysql.jar server.NithServer
```

But in linux it says:

```
-bash: server.jar: command not found
```

How can I add both `server.jar` and `mysql.jar` in Centos 5?

Comment: The `java` command syntax isn't the same on windows and *nix.  You need to read the documentation.

Comment: Didn't you copy something wrong??   Maybe it was 'java -cp mysql.jar;server.jar server.NithServer' and 'bash: server.jar: command not found'. Check my answer to understand why.

Comment: @AdimSoyadim Please mark one of the answers as correct if they were usefull to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `:` as the path separator, instead of `;`

Answer (score 1):

In **bash** the ';' character [separates shell commands](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) when you want to put them in the same line.

This means that the string that appears after ';' and before the next space is considered a new command.

This is why, in the Unix java command, ':' is used as a separator for jars in the '-cp' option. This also happens in other Unix commands as well.

So you should write:

```
    java -cp mysql.jar:server.jar server.NithServer
```

On another note, if you have these kind of difficulties again, try to call the 'man' command followed by the command you want to understand.

```
    man java
```

There, you will find the answer to your question, right where the '-cp' option is described.

Enjoy.